# Multiple COUNTs in MYSQL with condition on individual column

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table mentioned below and I'm trying to get total count based on condition with field `cont` and group by entry

***someTable***

```
    ID    guid      entry    cont
    ---   -----     -----    -----
    1     g1        e1       NULL
    2     g2        e2       NULL
    3     g1        e1       NULL
    4     g3        e1       72345
    5     g1        e3       NULL
    6     g2        e2       34567
```

#### The desired Result is

```
    entry    total_c   total_con
    ---      -----      ----------
    e1       3          1
    e2       2          1
    e3       1          0
```

I am using the following query, but it returns total_con of whole table for each row

```
SELECT entry, count(*) AS total_c, (SELECT count(*) FROM someTable WHERE cont IS NOT NULL) AS total_con FROM someTable GROUP BY entry
```

which is giving

```
    entry    total_c   total_con
    ---      -----      ----------
    e1       3          2
    e2       2          2
    e3       1          2
```

How should i achieve the result?
Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  entry, 
  count(*) AS total_c, 
  sum(cont is not null) AS total_con 
FROM someTable 
GROUP BY entry
```

The expression `cont is not null` evaluates to `0` or `1` so `SUM()` sums over these values.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7JfzGJpmbxvT7bNbG62WYo/0).
Results:

```
| entry | total_c | total_con |
| ----- | ------- | --------- |
| e1    | 3       | 1         |
| e2    | 2       | 1         |
| e3    | 1       | 0         |
```

Comment: I guess, i'll change my accepted answer to yours as i'm still not very much clear about the concept but this seems pretty straight forward concept for the problem. Sorry for my confusion

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional statement for the third column :

```
select entry, count(*) as total_c, 
       sum(case when cont is not null then 1 else 0 end) as total_con
  from someTable
 group by entry
```

or replace `total_con` column with `sum(sign(ifnull(cont ,1)))` as an alternative.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ee3ade766408f3358456e731e685b116)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You would just use `COUNT()`.  It does exactly what you want:

```
SELECT entry, COUNT(*) AS total_c, 
       COUNT(cont) AS total_con 
FROM someTable 
GROUP BY entry;
```

`COUNT()` counts the number of non-NULL values.